# How can I remove a background tr color from a Twitter Bootstrap table?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) v 2.0.1 and have given my table the table-striped class.  I'm trying to change a row color if clicked.  This works great except for every n:th row that doesn't have a stripe color.  I assume I need to remove the striped color first but my attempt is failing.  Any idea what I'm missing?

HTML

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Col 1</th>
                <th>Col 2</th>
                <th>Col 3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Data 1</strong></td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Data 1</strong></td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Data 1</strong></td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

My jQuery attempt(s):

```
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function(){

    $('tr').click( function() {
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('table-striped');
        //$(this).css('background-color', '#ff0000').siblings().removeClass('table-striped');
     });
});

</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well since they are created by using: `tr:nth-child(odd) td`, we can't simply "remove" the class **table-striped**, since it would effect the entire table.

Create your own class let's say: `.highlightBG { background:#5279a4; }`

And do this instead:

```
$('table.table-striped tr').on('click', function () {
    $(this).find('td').addClass('highlightBG');
    // potentially even .toggleClass('highlightBG'); to alternate it
});
```

Comment: That makes sense...your suggestion worked, Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is it possible to use toggle with a css selector? A user can define the background color so ultimately I would like to toggle: $(this).find('td').css('background-color', '#ff0000');

Answer (score 0):

table-striped is a class on the table, not the `<tr>` or siblings, so either create a new class to toggle on `<tr>` or jQuery `parents('table')` or change `$(this)` to `$('table.table')`

In the end I think you want to keep the striping on all the other rows, and change the current selected, if that is the case then use the first suggestion and override with a new css class on `$(this)`  Don't remove table-striped and make sure your new class has a higher specificity.