# How do I toggle a table row background color for Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

In reference to my earlier [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12624472/how-can-i-remove-a-background-tr-color-from-a-twitter-bootstrap-table):

My HTML

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Col 1</th>
            <th>Col 2</th>
            <th>Col 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Data 1</strong></td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Data 1</strong></td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Data 1</strong></td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table.table-striped tr').on('click', function () {
        $(this).find('td').css('background-color', '#ff0000');

         // toggleClass doesn't seem to work

     });
 });
```

I'm trying to toggle the row color off an on via my click event.  Any idea if this is possible using a user defined css selector?

Comment: Do you have a class in the first place to be toggled. ?? Looks like your assigning the background-color in CSS right

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may try this

**CSS**

```
.bg{background-color:#ff0000 !important;}​
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table.table-striped tbody tr').on('click', function () {
        $(this).closest('table').find('td').removeClass('bg');
        $(this).find('td').addClass('bg');
    });
});​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rgSBE/1/).

**Update:** For toggling

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table.table-striped tbody tr').on('click', function () {
        $(this).find('td').toggleClass('bg');
    });
});​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rgSBE/2/).

Comment: That seems to work but ideally I need the ability to toggle the same row...any thoughts?

Comment: Didn't understand toggle same row, can you explain ?

Comment: I actually got it working using your sample. I changed it to: $(this).find('td').toggleClass('bg'); Thanks for the help and great example!